# Example of a homogeneous polynomial in $R^2$ which is not hyperbolic and how would its graph behave.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am doing a desertation and presently as a part of it I am learning about hyperbolic polynomial. To understand exactly what kind of Homogenous polynomials  are non-hyperbolic I am looking for some examples which would enhance my understanding of it.
Please provide some examples and also some tips to better understand the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I got an example finally!!!
Consider p(x,y)=$x^2+y^2$ which is homogeneous polynomial in $R$[x,y].
Also consider (1,1) in $R^2$ ,clearly p(1,1)>0.
But given (a,b)in ${R}^2$, p((a-t,b-t)) has imaginary root as a=1+t and b=t+$i$ which makes it non-hyperbolic.